# Permission denied when writing logs in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, unix, docker-container, docker-logs

I was trying to write a Docker log file on Ubuntu 20.04 by

```
sudo docker logs CONTAINER_ID >output.log
```

But it returned

```
-bash: output.log: Permission denied
```

How to solve the permission problem to save the logs? Is the problem inside the container or outside of it?

P.S. I had this container by `docker run -d -v ~/desktop/usercode/Docker:/code -p 5000:5000 flask_app:1.0`, and the Dockerfile is as below:

```
## Base Python Image for App
FROM python:3.9-rc-buster


# Setting up Docker environment
# Setting Work directory for RUN CMD commands
WORKDIR /code
# Export env variables.
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
###


#Copy requirements file from current directory to file in
#containers code directory we have just created.
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

#Run and install all required modules in container
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

#Copy current directory files to containers code directory
COPY . .

#RUN app.
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

And, the images are:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
flask_app    1.0             90b2840f4d5d   29 minutes ago   895MB
python       3.9-rc-buster   50625b35cf42   9 months ago     884MB
```

Comment: See [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  This is not Docker-related; it has to do with the order in which the shell first sets up the redirect and then runs `sudo`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you David! It did help print logs out. However, only [part of the logs are printed](https://imgur.com/a/zZV6J6X). May I ask why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you entered first creates `output.log` file in the same direction as you are, then drops the logs in that file; It seems that the problem is solved if you use the following command.

```
 docker logs CONTAINER_ID > ~/output.log
```

This command creates a log file in the root path of the user you are. for example if your username is `USER1` that file create at /home/USER1

Comment: Thank you. This helps save a log file. So the problem of my command is that the output.log created first can't be edited? What's the difference of process between yours and mine?

Comment: Also, only [part of the logs](https://imgur.com/a/TJe9fLY) are printed instead of whole logs shown in terminal. Are the printed logs and logs in file different?

Comment: hello @chenghuayang thanks for accepting my answer. if you want to print whole logs to this file please use this command  `docker logs CONTAINER_ID  >> ~/output.log 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks! What does `2>&1` mean? (Or is there some docs about it? I'm not sure what to search about it.)

Comment: 1 is for standard output (stdout) and 2 is for standard error (stderr) and `2>&1` means  redirects stderr to specific file and appending &1 redirects stderr to stdout. @chenghuayang